# R-variable in knitr chunk option

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is it possible to replace TRUE/FALSE in the knitr chunk-options by a variable:

Not

````
```{r,eval=TRUE}

do something

```
````

But

````
```{r}
boolean<-is.character(var)
```

```{r, eval=boolean}
do something
```
````

I know I can get the same result if I put `do something` in an if-statement, but `eval=boolean` would result in cleaner code, I think.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can specify that `boolean=FALSE` and use `eval=boolean` in your knitr chunk option. In the knitting process, that chunk won't be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks! The proposed duplicate-question also helped. I feel quite silly I didn't just try it before asking the question.